# Difference between these two methods of inputting elements of a vector? Which is more efficient?

Tags: c++, vector

Is the memory allocated to the vector dynamically in both cases or statically in 1st case and dynamically in 2nd?

1st

```
vector<int>::size_type n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> a(n);

for(vector<int>::size_type i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>a[i];
```

2nd

```
vector<int>::size_type n;
int temp;
cin>>n;
vector<int> a;

for(vector<int>::size_type i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>temp;
    a.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory will be allocated dynamically (from heap) in both cases, but you will get only one allocation for first case and multiple reallocations in second. Actual number of reallocation in second case is somewhere between 1 and n.

Comment: Which is more efficient?

Comment: you should also maybe state that when using something besides an int there is default constructor overhead to be taken into account.

Comment: @user3016220 Most efficient solution is given by Vlad from Moscow. `reserve()` does not construct objects that will be thrown away (as `resize()` do in first case), and there will be no reallocations.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases the memory for elements is allocated dynamically. In the second case the memory reallocated almost each time when a new element is added. You could make these two cases equivalent if in the second case you would write

```
vector<int> a;
a.reserve( n );
```

Comment: The memory is not allocated anywhere near as often as each time a new element is added.  It will be O(log n), not O(n) allocations.

Comment: What John Zwinck said. It's rare for `vector` to reallocate more often than 5-6 times. You'd really need a LOT of items for that to happen. Your argument is true for `list` and some unusual implementations of `deque`, however.

Comment: @John Zwinck, For example in MS VC++ 2010 when 10 elements are added to a vector then the capacity is being changed the following way 0
1
2
3
4
6
6
9
9
9

Answer (score 0):

The memory must be allocated dynamically in both cases, since more elements can be added to the vector in both cases.